# fire from a weapon of project motion using phaser 2.5.0

Tags: phaser-framework

i have a bow in bottom right corner. i need to throw arrow upward in projectile motion. [Project Motion article here](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/vectors/Lesson-2/What-is-a-Projectile)

thanks in advance

Comment: So what is your question? I'm assuming you are asking how to do this. You can simply create a weapon object with arrow image, and apply gravity.

Comment: i tried but did not work.

Comment: At least post what you have tried and ask specific questions. Are you expecting us to write code for you? It could be few fix away from your code.